# SQL , size finally matter

Tags: sql, buffer

I have an issue in an automatic job which is supposed to run each day. This job uses the SQL request below but I have too many values so I can't obtain any results because I have this error:

> ORA-19011: Character string buffer too small
> 19011. 00000 -  "Character string buffer too small"
> *Cause:    The string result asked for is too big to return back
> *Action:   Get the result as a lob instead

I tried many way to correct this but I have no solution to keep the same result with a different request.

For me the problem is in the bolded part of the request. ( my database is in oracle 11C )

If somebody has an idea to help me it could be perfect.

This is the request:

```
select 
'{"MARQUE":"'||MARQUE||'",'||
'"RAYON":"'||RAYON||'",'||
'"CATEGORIE":"'||CATEGORIE||'",'||
'"SS_CATEGORIE":"'||SS_CATEGORIE||'",'||
'"THEME":"'||THEME||'",'||
'"REFERENCE":"'||REFERENCE||'",'||
'"COULEUR":"'||COULEUR||'",'||
'"LIB_COULEUR":"'||LIB_COULEUR||'",'||
'"LIBELLE":"'||LIBELLE||'",'||
'"DESCRIPTIF":"'||to_clob(DESCRIPTIF)||'",'||
'"LIB_MINT":"'||LIB_MINT||'",'||
'"LIB_MAXT":"'||LIB_MAXT||'",'||
'"PV":"'||PV||'",'||
'"PV_PROMO":"'||PV_PROMO||'",'||
'"SKU":"'||SKU||'",'||
'"DISPO":"'|| decode(QTE_STK,0,'N','O')  ||'",'||
'"FLAGS":[' || 
substr(case when LIB_MAXT in ('52','54','64','XXXL') THEN '"GRANDE TAILLE",' ELSE '' END ||
case when DATE_DEBUT> trunc(sysdate-30) THEN '"NOUVEAUTE",' ELSE '' END ,
1, length(case when LIB_MAXT in ('52','54','64','XXXL')  THEN '"GRANDE TAILLE",' ELSE '' END ||
case when DATE_DEBUT> trunc(sysdate-30) THEN '"NOUVEAUTE",' ELSE '' END ) -1)
|| '] ,' || 
'"SAISON":"'||SAISON||'",'||
'"EANS":"'||EANS||'",'||
'"TAILLES":'||TAILLES||
decode(TRADUCTION, null,'',','||to_clob(TRADUCTION))||
'}' as final
from
(select distinct 
        a.id_enseigne,
        decode(a.id_entite,600,'JUL',2600,'BZB',3600,'BRI') as marque,
        p.id_rayon as rayon,
        trim(upper(f.lib_famille)) as categorie,
        trim(upper(sf.lib_sous_famille)) as ss_categorie,
        a.date_debut,
        replace(replace(replace(upper(upper(nvl(p.theme,''))) ,CHR(13),''),CHR(10),'. '),'"','`') as theme,
        a.id_ref as reference,
        lpad(a.id_couleur,4,'0') as couleur,
        replace(replace(replace(upper(c.lib_couleur) ,CHR(13),''),CHR(10),'. '),'"','`') as lib_couleur,
        replace(replace(replace(nvl(plg.lib_comm,'') ,CHR(13),''),CHR(10),'. '),'"','`') as libelle,
        replace(replace(replace(nvl(plg.descriptif,''),CHR(13),''),CHR(10),'. '),'"','`') as descriptif,
        FIRST_VALUE(t.lib_taille)
         OVER (PARTITION BY t.id_grille_taille, a.id_ref
               ORDER BY a.id_taille asc) as lib_mint,
        FIRST_VALUE(t.lib_taille)
         OVER (PARTITION BY t.id_grille_taille, a.id_ref
               ORDER BY a.id_taille desc) as lib_maxt,
        a.pv_init_e as pv,
        lp.pv_promo as pv_promo,
        FIRST_VALUE(a.id_article_int)
         OVER (PARTITION BY a.id_ref, a.id_couleur
               ORDER BY a.id_article_int asc) as sku,
        MAX(a.id_saison)
         OVER (PARTITION BY a.id_ref, a.id_couleur) as saison,
       (select sum(s.qte_stk) 
        from   ecomm.stock s, ecomm.article a2
        where  s.id_enseigne=a2.id_enseigne
        and    s.id_entite=a2.id_entite
        and    s.id_article_int=a2.id_article_int
        and    a.id_enseigne = a2.id_enseigne
        and    a.id_ref=a2.id_ref
        and    a.id_couleur =a2.id_couleur) AS qte_stk,
       (select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, c.code_barre || ',')).extract('//text()').extract('//text()') ,',') code_barre 
        from   ecomm.code_barre c
        where  c.id_enseigne=a.id_enseigne
        and    c.id_ref=a.id_ref
        and    c.id_couleur=a.id_couleur
        and    rownum < 100 ) AS eans, 
       (select replace('['||rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, '{ @ID@:@'||t2.id_taille||'@,@CODE@:@'||t2.lib_taille||'@}' || ',')).extract('//text()').extract('//text()') ,',') || ']','@','"') taille 
        from   ecomm.article a2,  ecomm.taille t2, ecomm.stock s2
        where  a.id_enseigne=a2.id_enseigne
        and    a.id_entite=a2.id_entite
        and    a.id_ref=a2.id_ref
        and    a.id_couleur=a2.id_couleur
        and    p.id_grille_taille=t2.id_grille_taille
        and    a2.id_taille=t2.id_taille
        and    a2.id_enseigne=s2.id_enseigne
        and    a2.id_entite=s2.id_entite
        and    a2.id_article_int=s2.id_article_int ) tailles,
       (select replace(rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e, '@LIBELLE_'||CD_LG_ISO639_2B||'@:@'||LIB_COMM||'@,@DESCRIPTIF_'||CD_LG_ISO639_2B||'@:@'||DESCRIPTIF||'@,')).extract('//text()').extract('//text()') ,',') ,'@','"') traduction
        from   ecomm.produit_lg c 
        where  c.id_enseigne=a.id_enseigne
        and    c.id_ref=a.id_ref ) traduction
from    ecomm.article a
join    ecomm.produit_LG plg        on  a.id_ref = plg.id_ref 
                                    and cd_lg_iso639_2b='FRE'
join    ecomm.produit p             on  plg.id_ref = p.id_ref
join    ecomm.famille f             on  p.id_famille=f.id_famille
join    ecomm.sous_famille sf       on  p.id_sous_famille=sf.id_sous_famille
join    ecomm.couleur c             on  a.id_couleur=c.id_couleur
join    ecomm.entite_ecomm ee       on  a.id_entite = ee.id_entite
join    ecomm.enseigne e            on  e.id_enseigne = ee.id_enseigne
join    ecomm.taille t              on  p.id_grille_taille = t.id_grille_taille 
                                    and a.id_taille = t.id_taille
left join 
  (select liaison_promo.id_enseigne, liaison_promo.id_ref,liaison_promo.id_couleur, liaison_promo.pv_promo
  from ecomm.liaison_promo, ecomm.promo 
  where liaison_promo.id_promo= promo.id_promo
  and   (promo.dath_debut is null or (promo.dath_debut < sysdate and promo.dath_fin >sysdate))
  and (promo.id_entite is null or promo.id_entite in (600,2600,3600))  )  lp
                                    on  lp.id_enseigne=a.id_enseigne
                                    and lp.id_ref=a.id_ref
                                    and lp.id_couleur=a.id_couleur
where a.id_enseigne = 1
and   a.date_debut < sysdate 
and a.id_ref_parent_print is null
) req
where (req.saison= (select max(id_collection) from ecomm.collection c where c.encours='O' and c.id_enseigne=req.id_enseigne) or req.qte_stk>0)
  order by categorie, saison desc, qte_stk desc, reference, couleur;
```

Comment: Please remove one of the dubs. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67799661/sql-size-finally-matter

Comment: Do you have an option to upgrade your 15 years old database to one that has dedicated JSON support, (or install some packages to help), rather than having to string it together yourself? How about selecting it normally and having the front end convert to json?